# iterate thu each row in a column and update

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have sql server table column named "Subject.

```
UPDATE mytable SET SUBJECT=HASHBYTES('SHA1',SUBJECT)from  mytable
```

The query above hash entire rows in subject column ...

```
0x0431A163506AE958501A2AA30FA12513C3CE599A
0x0431A163506AE958501A2AA30FA12513C3CE599A
0x0431A163506AE958501A2AA30FA12513C3CE599A
```

The output row values will be same for each records in subject column.

I will need to read each row and hash it and update instead of coloumn based hashing. how can i do that.

```
0x0431A163506AE958501A2AA30FA12513C3CE599A
0x0431A163506AE958501A2AA30FA12513C3CE593D
0x0431A163506AE958501A2AA30FA12513C3CE592F
```

Comment: Are the values different though?  If they are, you might need to include another value - perhaps the primary key for the table?

Comment: In subject column.. the rows are different... so can provide a query how to loop throgh each row and hash it... i do hav primary column named ID..

Comment: Just a thought.  What type is SUBJECT?  Remember that HASHBYTES is returning a VARBINARY, and if SUBJECT is an NVARCHAR that may cause issues.

Comment: To do this row by row, you can use a CURSOR or WHILE loop.  While loop is nicer.  Just use your primary key.

Comment: NVARCHAR(255)...hashing is the not issue here... i managed to hash  column "SUBJECT" ...but output show are the same for each rows records in SUBJECT column. I will need to read each row and hash it and update instead of coloumn based hashing. how can i do that

Comment: i m very new sql query ...hw do i do that.. assumae my table name is mytable and column name is SUBJECT..

Comment: The update statement what you have posted works correctly. Why you really need a loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This assumes that your primary key is called subjectID.

```
DECLARE @currentKEY INT
DECLARE @maxKey INT

SELECT @currentKey = MIN(subjectID), @maxKey = MAX(subjectID) FROM mytable

WHILE @currentKey <= @maxKEY
BEGIN
  UPDATE myTable
  SET SUBJECT = HASHBYTES('SHA1', SUBJECT)
  WHERE subjectID = @currentKEY

  SELECT @currentKey = MIN(subjectID) FROM mytable WHERE subjectID > @currentKey
END
```

If you want to do it as a cursor, I can show you how to do that too.

Comment: WHERE subjectID = @currentKEY AND HASHBYTES('SHA1', SUBJECT) from mytable

Comment: how do assign each rows of SUBJECT column to hash input.. .

Comment: Updated code above to include HASHBYTES('SHA1', SUBJECT).

Comment: You cant use AND HASHBYTES.. it doesn't work that way.  If what I've posted above is not what you're looking for, I'm afraid I don't understand your question properly.  When I do UPDATE table SET hashvalue=HASHBYTES('SHA1', value) I get a unique value for each row.  No duplication at all.  However, I can't update an NVARCHAR with a VARBINARY as it results in corruption.  Even trying to cast the result of HASHBYTES to NVARCHAR doesn't work.